# Apply Sitecore validation rule to a field type?

Tags: validation, sitecore, treelist, fieldtype

I have created a validation rule in Core DB, and I have created a custom Sitecore field called 'Single Select Treelist'. I want to apply this validation rule to all 'Single Select Treelist' fields in all templates in my Sitecore instance.
I know we can individually apply the validation rule to each template field of type 'Single Select Treelist'. Is there a way to achieve this automatically for all 'Single Select Treelist' fields without any custom coding?

I see the list of field type validation rules available in Master:
[image]

How are these connected to the respective field types in Core?

[image]

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

If you edit the field type item there is a validation section that contains fields to set validation rules for the Quick Action Bar, the Validate Button, the Validator Bar and finally Workflow.

[image: ![![Validation Fields]

Once you set the validation rules, depending on which field you set, Sitecore will display the validation messages in different ways. See this blog post for examples: http://sitecoreworld.blogspot.com/2014/12/sitecore-validation-examples.html

Comment: But I would expect to associate a field type validation to a field type. I see the provision to only add item rules here. Additionally, adding validation rules here doesn't seem to apply to rule to all fields of this type

Answer (score 0):

The link between the Field Type Validation Rule and the actual Field Type seems to be based simply on the name of the Field Type.

Just add a new item with the template "Field Type Validation Rules" in the Validation Rules/Field Types folder that you show in your picture. Give it the exact same name as the field type you want it to validate. Select the rules you need inside the Validation Rules section of that new object.

For example, I just needed to add some validation to the Single-Line Text type, as you can see in the image. We struggled with it for a little while because we missed the dash. 
[Image - Sitecore Tree with new Field Type Validation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOtOs.png)